# Duración de Token JWT

Tags: typescript, jwt

Estoy trabajando en una API REST donde se está utilizando Tokens JWT,pero surgió la duda en mi de si se puede enviar la fecha a expirar, por decir si hoy se inicia el token "Wed, 26 Aug 2020 00:00:00" (UTC-0), ¿podría enviar que el token venza por decir el "Wed, 26 Aug 2021 23:59:59" (UTC-0)?

El código con el que envió el JWT es el siguiente:

```
const token = jwt.sign({ idProfile: this.users.idProfile, isAdmin: this.users.isAdmin }, 'secret', { expiresIn: '1h'});

res.status(200).json(token)
```

La parte que deseo saber si hay como cambiar o enviar una fecha en concreto vendría a ser la parte de  {expiresIn: 'Aquí debería de poder agregar la fecha'}, pero de momento no se si funcione como tal enviando así mismo con expiresIn o si habrá un expiresAt.

Comment: Sin saber qué librería usas para generar ese token es complicado saber qué parametros puedes o no pasar. Pero por lo general todas las librerías de jwt que conozco tienen alguna manera de asignar una duración al token, te recomiendo que busques la documentación de tu librería.

Comment: Es decir, yo como usuario puedo modificar la expiración del token y ponerla en el año 3000? Estás seguro que quieres que se comporte así?

Answer (score 0):

Viendo el codigo que pusiste, pienso que estas utilizando `jsonwebtoken`. Normal mente unto no dice cuando se vence al cliente porque el servidor es el unico a el que le importa la expiracion. El servidor entonces se encarga en chequear si el token esta expirado o si tiene que renovar. Pero bueno, ademas de decir eso, si en verdad quieres mandarle al cliente cuando el token se expira, entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente.

Nota:

- Utilizo moment porque utilizando Date causa raras conversiones de tiempo en este ejemplo.
- El 60*60 es porque en tu ejemplo quieres que se venza en 1hr

**Solucion 1:**

Agarra el exp de la token

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const moment = require('moment');

jwt.sign({
  data: 'foobar'
}, 'secret', { expiresIn: 60 * 60 }, (e, token) => {
    const payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secret');
    res.json({
       token,
       expiresIn: moment(payload.exp * 1000),
    });
});
```

**Solucion 2:**

No agarra el exp de la token sino que lo calculamos

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const moment = require('moment');

const exp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60);
const expiresIn = moment(exp * 1000);

jwt.sign({
  data: 'foobar',
  exp,
}, 'secret', (e, token) => {
    res.json({
       token,
       expiresIn,
    });
});
```